# Nesting a WITH statement into an existing select and passing dates into it

Tags: sql, oracle

I have found an excellent solution on here that will allow me to compare number working days between 2 dates excluding holidays. However what I cannot figure out is how to pass t1.ATTRIBUTE_DATE1 into the start_date and t1.CHECK_DATE into the end_date.

I have tried and put the With into the select it says too many arguments.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT t1.invoice_date
    ,      t1.creation_date
    ,      t1.INVOICE_RECEIVED_DATE
    ,      (t1.check_Date - t1.INVOICE_RECEIVED_DATE)
    ,      ((t1.check_Date - t2.REPORT_SUBMIT_DATE)+3)
    ,      ((t1.check_Date - t1.invoice_date)+3)
    ,      t1.ATTRIBUTE_DATE1
    ,      t1.invoice_num
    ,      t1.payment_number
    ,      t1.check_date
    ,      t1.vendor_type_lookup_code
    ,      t1.source
    ,      t1.PAY_GROUP_LOOKUP_CODE
    ,      t1.Batch_Name
    ,      t1.Description
    ,      t1.Vendor_Name
    ,      t1.Amount_Paid
    ,      t1.Invoice_ID
    ,      t2.REPORT_SUBMIT_DATE
    ,      t2.FINAL_APPROVAL_DATE



 FROM   ( SELECT DISTINCT APA.INVOICE_ID 
        ,      APA.INVOICE_DATE
        ,      APA.CREATION_DATE
        ,      APA.ATTRIBUTE_DATE1
        ,      APA.INVOICE_NUM
        ,      ACA.CHECK_NUMBER as PAYMENT_NUMBER
        ,      ACA.CHECK_DATE
        ,      APA.INVOICE_RECEIVED_DATE
        ,      APA.CREATION_DATE   
        ,      SUP.VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE
        ,      APA.SOURCE   
        ,      APA.PAY_GROUP_LOOKUP_CODE
        ,      BAT.BATCH_NAME
        ,      APA.DESCRIPTION
        ,      APA.AMOUNT_PAID
        ,      ACA.VENDOR_NAME

        FROM AP_INVOICES_ALL APA

        LEFT JOIN  AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL   AIL
        ON APA.INVOICE_ID= AIL.INVOICE_ID

        LEFT JOIN AP_INVOICE_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL   AID
        ON APA.INVOICE_ID = AID.INVOICE_ID AND AIL.LINE_NUMBER = 
        AID.INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER


    JOIN   AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS_ALL AIP
    ON     APA.INVOICE_ID = AIP.INVOICE_ID

    JOIN   AP_CHECKS_ALL ACA
    ON     AIP.CHECK_ID = ACA.CHECK_ID

    LEFT JOIN AP_BATCHES_ALL BAT
    ON APA.BATCH_ID = BAT.BATCH_ID

    LEFT JOIN POZ_SUPPLIERS_V SUP
    ON   APA.PARTY_ID = SUP.PARTY_ID


    WHERE AID.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE    = 'ITEM'
    AND   APA.SOURCE NOT IN ('INVOICE GATEWAY' , 'B2B XML INVOICE')
    AND   ACA.STATUS_LOOKUP_CODE<> 'VOIDED' 
    AND   APA.INVOICE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE NOT IN ('CREDIT' , 'PREPAYMENT')
    AND   ACA.CHECK_DATE BETWEEN  :Start_Date AND :End_Date
    AND   BAT.BATCH_NAME IS NOT NULL) t1

      LEFT JOIN (Select  EXPENSE_REPORT_NUM
                 ,REPORT_SUBMIT_DATE
                 ,FINAL_APPROVAL_DATE
                 ,EXPENSE_REPORT_TOTAL

                 FROM EXM_EXPENSE_REPORTS)t2 

      ON t1.INVOICE_NUM =t2.EXPENSE_REPORT_NUM


 ORDER BY t1.CHECK_DATE ASC
```

With statment that I would like to use to give me days between t1.ATTRIBUTE_DATE1(can be blank) and t1.check_date

```
(WITH test_data AS
  (
     SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS start_date,-----t1.ATTRIBUTE_DATE1
            TO_DATE('27/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS end_date------t1.check_date

       FROM dual
  ), 
all_dates AS 
(

    SELECT td.start_date, td.end_date, td.start_date + LEVEL-1 as week_day
      FROM test_data td
   CONNECT BY td.start_date + LEVEL-1 <=  td.end_date)
   SELECT TO_CHAR(week_day, 'MON'),  COUNT(*)

 FROM all_dates 
 WHERE to_char(week_day, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')  NOT IN 
('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')
 AND to_char(week_day, 'DD/MM/YYYY') NOT IN ( '01/01/2019', '25/12/2019', 
'26/12/2019', '26/08/2019', '19/04/2019', '22/04/2019', '06/05/2019', 
'27/05/2019')
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(week_day, 'MON')
 )
```

---

Want to replace the the above with statement with this

```
(WITH test_data AS
      (
        SELECT TO_DATE(t1.ATTRIBUTE_DATE1, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS start_date,
               TO_DATE(t1.check_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS end_date

          FROM dual
     ), 
    all_dates AS 
    (

        SELECT td.start_date, td.end_date, td.start_date + LEVEL-1 as week_day
          FROM test_data td
       CONNECT BY td.start_date + LEVEL-1 <=  td.end_date)
       SELECT TO_CHAR(week_day, 'MON'),  COUNT(*)

    FROM all_dates 
    WHERE to_char(week_day, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')  NOT IN ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')
  AND to_char(week_day, 'DD/MM/YYYY') NOT IN ( '01/01/2019', '25/12/2019', '26/12/2019', '26/08/2019', '19/04/2019', '22/04/2019', '06/05/2019', '27/05/2019')
  GROUP BY TO_CHAR(week_day, 'MON')
 )
```

Comment: Can you please compress your *excellent solution* a bit, so that we can focus on your actual problem. I.e. *remove all lines that are not necesssary*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clue what your real issue is, but if you want to count working days between 2 dates you can use something like:

```
with test_data AS
(SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS start_date,    -- t1.ATTRIBUTE_DATE1
        TO_DATE('27/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS end_date       -- t1.check_date
   FROM dual
  union all 
 SELECT TO_DATE('01/04/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS start_date,    -- t1.ATTRIBUTE_DATE1
        TO_DATE('10/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS end_date       -- t1.check_date
   FROM dual)
,  dates as (
     select trunc(sysdate,'YYYY') + level -1 bd from dual connect by level <= 250)
, evaluate_free as (
     select bd
   , case when to_char(bd, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')   IN ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY')
         or to_char(bd, 'DD/MM/YYYY')  IN ( '01/01/2019', '25/12/2019', '26/12/2019', '26/08/2019', '19/04/2019', '22/04/2019', '06/05/2019', '27/05/2019') 
      then 0 else 1 end  free_work
   from dates)
select start_date,end_date, sum(free_work) working_days 
from   evaluate_free, test_data 
where  bd between start_date and end_date
group  by start_date,end_date
```

Comment: I want to replace the hard coded dates with the fields from the t1 query to bring a result for each row.

Comment: the with statement works perfectly with hard coded start and end dates

Comment: Tried modifying the above and insert into the select and get t1.check_date invalid indetifier

Comment: Please create a testable example which creates the testdata in the question. Otherwise it's not possible for me to help

Comment: Look at the above i simply want to pass 2 different dates from the first query into this and out as a value for each row.

Comment: Simple side note, I try to generate the dates in my example but without materialize hint I got scrambled data

Comment: If i use the example i attached at the begging with hard coded start and end dates it works fine, what i want to do is pass the start(ATTRIBUTE_DATE1) and end date(CHECK_DATE) from each row of the t1 query

Comment: I am thinking i may need a variable to store these dates into.